# How to install Tensorflow-Federated 0.28.0 on win10?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I need some function or api which belongs to the newest version of Tensorflow Federated. According to the tutorial of official website, I type the following to install the newest version.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated
```

Unfortunately, when the installation has been finished, the version is 0.17.0, which was published in 2020. Therefore, I just want to know how to install Tensorflow-Federated 0.28.0 on win10.

Comment: I have moved to Linux System, and everything is ok now. The win 10 platform can't download the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved to Linux System, and everything is ok now. The win 10 platform can't download the newest version.